# Jasper Report 5.5 - Summary with Page header and footer

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using the table in my jasper report.When i put the table in the detail section it repeats the table so i put it to the summary band.
I also want to add the page footer in my report too.

How can i do this jasper report 5.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iReport to design your report, there is an easy way to add/remove bands, such as a Page Footer. On the left, on the Report Inspector, if *"Page Footer"* is in light grey (which means it is not inserted), right click on it, and select *"Add Band"* :[image: bands]

Also, another way i deal with tables, is by adding all the tables column headers in a single row on the Title band positioned on the lower border of the band, and right down to them, again on a single row, all the TextFields containing the data (inside the Detail band). These way, the first row will be printed only once, and all the part in the detail band (which means all the rows of the table) will be printed. You have just to make a little cell formatting to make it appear with a table fashion (such as borders, background etc) which is very easy with iReport:
[image: table]